# sorting vector of structs by integer

Tags: c++

Im trying to sort vector of structs. I saw [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15640202/how-to-sort-a-vector-of-structs-based-on-a-vectorstring-within-the-vector-to-b) examples.

this is my code:

.h file:

```
// I didn't mention all the includes and namespace
class fileLoader
{
 struct commands
  {
    int time;
    string name;
  };
 commands resultStruct;
 vector<commands> resultVector

  private:
     void sortFunction();
     bool compareByTime(const commands &a, const commands &b);
}
```

.cpp file:

```
void fileLoader::sortResults()
{
    sort(resultVector.begin(), resultVector.end(), compareByTime);
}

bool fileLoader::compareByTime(const commands &a, const commands &b)
{
    return a.time < b.time;
}
```

this is the compilation error I get:

```
error C3867: 'fileLoader::compareByTime': function call missing argument list; use '&fileLoader::compareByTime' to create a pointer to member
error C2780: 'void std::sort(_RanIt,_RanIt)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm(3639) : see declaration of 'std::sort'
```

when I tried to change `compareByTime` to `&fileLoader::compareByTime`, I got this compilation error:

```
    error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm(3776) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> std::_Unguarded_partition<_RanIt,_Pr>(_RanIt,_RanIt,_Pr)' being compiled
    1>          with
    1>          [
    1>              _Ty1=fileLoader::commands *,
    1>              _Ty2=fileLoader::commands *,
    1>              _RanIt=fileLoader::commands *,
    1>              _Pr=bool (__thiscall fileLoader::* )(const fileLoader::commands &,const fileLoader::commands &)
    1>          ]
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm(3806) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Sort<fileLoader::commands*,__w64 int,_Pr>(_RanIt,_RanIt,_Diff,_Pr)' being compiled
    1>          with
    1>          [
    1>              _Pr=bool (__thiscall fileLoader::* )(const fileLoader::commands &,const fileLoader::commands &),
    1>              _RanIt=fileLoader::commands *,
    1>              _Diff=__w64 int
    1>          ]
   std::sort<std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>,bool(__thiscall fileLoader::* )(const fileLoader::commands &,const fileLoader::commands &)>(_RanIt,_RanIt,_Pr)' being compiled
    1>          with
    1>          [
    1>              _Myvec=std::_Vector_val<fileLoader::commands,std::allocator<fileLoader::commands>>,
    1>              _RanIt=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<fileLoader::commands,std::allocator<fileLoader::commands>>>,
    1>              _Pr=bool (__thiscall fileLoader::* )(const fileLoader::commands &,const fileLoader::commands &)
    1>          ]
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm(3720): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
    1>
    1>Build FAILED.
```

I will be happy for some help.

thanks.

Comment: compareByTime must be a static function

Comment: Or a non-member function.

Answer (score 1):

First fix all the typos (missing semicolons etc).

Then change your sorting function to `static bool compareByTime(const commands &a, const commands &b);`

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

Make `compareByTime` `static` (or 'global' outside class)

**Explanation**

Member functions require `this` to be passed to them somehow, so two argument member function is probably 3 argument function. So compiler can't use it when it needs 2 arguments comparator.

Comment: You need to use `std::bind` to do this.  If you're on older compilers, you're basically hooped.  But on newer ones, you're OK now.